# How to use C header files in org-mode source code blocks?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, c, file-header

I have a C code block in my org-mode document like the following:

```
#+begin_src C :exports both
#include "my_header.h"

int main(void)
{
    function_from_my_header();
    return 0;
}
#+end_src
```

When I have point inside the code block and `C-c C-c` to compile + generate results, I get the following error.

```
/var/folders/bc/2wq0dn651ys844kp5cz459mc0000gn/T/babel-SktA20/C-src-RnWgKS.c:8:10: fatal error: 'my_header.h' file not found
#include "my_header.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
zsh:1: permission denied: /var/folders/bc/2wq0dn651ys844kp5cz459mc0000gn/T/babel-SktA20/C-bin-DWq2ho
```

How do I get org-mode to recognize the header file (which is contained in the same directory as the org file?

It is worth noting: everything has worked fine so far if I don't have (custom) headers (e.g., includes for `stdio.h` etc. work fine). It is also worth noting that if I save the source code block to a file and compile using gcc, then the file compiles fine. Ergo, it seems the missing piece is determining how to get org-mode to recognize `my_header.h`, which lies in the same directory as the org file itself.

---

### Edit: Solved

I did as [NickD suggested](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/62869/29560) but still got an error. To be precise, I have the three files

- `my_header.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "my_header.h"

void my_function(void)
{
    printf("I can C clearly now.\n");
}
```

- `my_header.h` (contains only the prototype for `my_function`.
- `my_test.c`

```
#include "my_header.h"

int main(void)
{
    my_function();
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and link from the command line (from within the directory in which these files reside), I run:

```bash
gcc my_test.c my_header.c -o my_test && ./my_test
```

Everything works perfectly.

Now, if I run the following code block from within an org-mode document (residing in the same directory):

```
#+begin_src C :flags -I .
#include "my_header.h"

int main(void)
{
    my_function();
    return 0;
}
#+end_src
```

I get the following error message from the compiler:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_my_function", referenced from:
      _main in C-src-fboHG7-40f2c1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
zsh:1: no such file or directory: /var/folders/bc/2wq0dn651ys844kp5cz459mc0000gn/T/babel-SktA20/C-bin-9wLHvS
```

The fix (in addition to setting `:flags -I.` was to also set `:includes my_header.c`

**The following works perfectly for me when I** `C-c C-c` **in org:**

```
#+begin_src C :flags -I . :includes my_header.c
int main(void)
{
    my_function();
    return 0;
}
#+end_src
```

### Question summary

*How do I get org-mode to recognize the header file (which is contained in the same directory as the org file?*

You don't. You point it to the *source file* corresponding to the header (i.e., `my_header.c`) by `include`-ing `my_header.c`.

Why is this the expected behaviour? My understanding is that this flag creates an `#include "my_header.c"` line in the temporary `.c` file, and that this is not standard practice when writing C code (one usually includes the `.h` file).

Comment: Please do *NOT* change the question after the fact: ask a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution involves a step beyond what was described in NickD's answer.

The following is correct - both in terms of C style and org-mode style.

```
#+begin_src C :flags -I. my_header.c
#include "my_header.h"

int main(void)
{
    function_from_my_header();
    return 0;
}
#+end_src
```

Equivalently, one could write

```
#+begin_src C :flags -I. my_header.c :includes my_header.h
function_from_my_header();
#+end_src
```

This can be gleaned from how the `#+CALL` is described in [the org manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Evaluating-Code-Blocks.html#Evaluating-Code-Blocks), noting that the call to `gcc` should look like:

```
gcc -o <executable_name> <code_block_name.c> my_header.c -I.
```

(In particular, `my_header.c` needs to appear in the call to `gcc`, and `:flags` is the appropriate place to include that. Importantly, `my_header.c` should **not** be placed in the `:includes` header arg. This is bad C practice and can have unintended consequences.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to arrange that `gcc` is called with the flag `-I .` that tells the preprocessor to look in the current directory (as well as the default directories). You can do that with

```
#+begin_src C :exports both :flags -I .
#include "my_header.h"

int main(void)
{
    function_from_my_header();
    return 0;
}
#+end_src
```

Why that is needed and why you don't need anything like that when you invoke `gcc` from the command line is a bit subtle: Org babel creates a temporary file `/var/folders/bc/2wq0dn651ys844kp5cz459mc0000gn/T/babel-SktA20/C-src-RnWgKS.c` (as you can see in the error message), with the source code from the code block inserted, but note it's in some temporary directory, *not* in the directory where your Org mode file and `my_header.h` are. So the compilation fails. Try copying your C file to some other directory and then on the command line saying `gcc -o /path/to/other/directory/foo /path/to/other/directory/foo.c`: it will fail the same way.

By giving it the `-I .` flag, you are saying "search for include files in the current directory, as well as in the standard include directories", i.e. you are effectively executing `gcc -o /path/to/other/directory/foo -I . /path/to/other/directory/foo.c` *from the directory where your Org mode file and your `my_header.h` file are*: since your current directory does contain `my_header.h`, the preprocessor can find it and everything works.

There are several other header arguments for C code blocks that are described in the relevant [Babel Language page](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-C.html) on Worg (`:libs` e.g. will be useful whenever you try to link with an external library). And if you venture to other languages, you might want to look at [their language-specific pages](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/index.html).

Comment: I updated my question to reflect new developments. I can get it to work - 50% due to your input (thank you!). I am confused about the remaining 50%. Why should it be necessary to `:includes` the `my_header.c` file?

Comment: Please don't change the question after it is answered: ask a different questions instead.

Comment: The original question is "How do I get org-mode to recognize a quoted header file?" and the uninformative answer (from what I can tell) is: "you don't. you point it to the header's source file". Asking for an explanation of that behaviour seems within scope for providing an informative answer.

Comment: The original question was: "Why do I get an error when I use a header file in the current directory ?". I explained why in detail. You then added separate compilation into the question. That is now a different question which should be posted separately.

Comment: The original question is the one I've quoted (simply view my question above the Edit headline or read the edit history to confirm). Is "recognize" ambiguous somehow? Indeed, if I point org to the right directory using the `-I.` flag as you suggest, then the compiler recognizes the existence of the .h file but fails to compile because it *still* does not recognize the .c file.